# DataTable to List in C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I'm looking to convert one column of my datatable into a list of the strings using C#.  I've tried 4 other solutions that I've found on stackoverflow, some using LINQ and others using foreach loops.  None of them have worked thus far which is why I'm confused.  I'll include my datatable code.  One of the failed solutions is commented out in the code.

C#:

```
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(dt);
//failed solution 1
           // var list = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
           //.Select(dr => dr.Field<string>("CraftType")).ToList();

//failed solution 2
/* List<string> s = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x[6].ToString()).ToList();

             foreach (string e in s)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }*/

            return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used part of @RobertHarvey code.  They had too many loops, and `Console.Write` wasn't writing on my page.  This code snippet took the column I specified and wrote it as a list onto my page.

```
private void PrintTable(DataTable table)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        Response.Write(row[column] + "<br />");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterate the [`Columns` collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.columns(v=vs.110).aspx).  Example:

```
private void PrintTable(DataTable table)
{
    foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        PrintRow(table, row);
    }
}

private void PrintRow(DataTable table, DataRow row)
{
    foreach(DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.Write(row[column] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The code would be `Console.Write(row[column] + " ");`  but this still doesn't write anything even though I have data in my column.

Comment: Then you need to make it clear that this is the problem that you're having ... No data.

Comment: I said that I have data in my column.. I changed your code to `Response.Write` from `Console.Write` and it's displaying data now but your loops are running too many times.

Answer (score 2):

Since both your attempts were in LINQ, here's the solution using LINQ:

```
var strings = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row["(columnname)"].ToString());
```

I'm making the assumption you want strings by calling `.ToString()` on the row[col] values.  There's also no error checking here (e.g. existence of col / `DBNull` check)

To make this more convenient, I'd turn it into an extension method:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetDataInColumn(this DataColumn column)
    {
        return column.Table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row[column.ColumnName].ToString());
    }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Column1");
        table.Columns.Add("Column2");
        table.Rows.Add(new[] { "col1row1", "col2row1" });
        table.Rows.Add(new[] { "col1row2", "col2row2" });

        var strings = table.Columns["Column2"].GetDataInColumn();

        strings.ToList().ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

//Will output
//col2row1
//col2row2
```

Comment: Good answer, but I think it deserves a little more explanation. @user3267755 was trying to use Linq, which failed because DataRowCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>, but does implement IEnumerable. See base class [InternalDataCollectionBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase(v=vs.110).aspx). [Enumerable.Cast<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) allows Linq methods to work in such scenarios, because it creates a collection of IEnumerable<T> from IEnumerable.